# What data type should i use?

Tags: java, types, char

hi i have a java programming assignment  wich  include 3 exercice i have done 2 already but in the third one i am dont know wich data type i should use 
here is the question :

Write a java program that reads from the user the course code, section and the scores of a student for three exams representing two midterms and a final. The percentage of each of the three exams is of fixed value 30, 30 and 40 percent respectively. Your program computes the final average grade and displays it along with the course code and the section. 
Remark: All data, except for the average, must be whole numbers and you should use the most efficient data type that is suitable for this specific exercise.

Sample Run:

Enter your course code: CSCI250

Enter your section: E

Enter the scores of the tests and the final: 97 83 77

CSCI250 E 84.8  (result)

---

so what i want to know is what is the preferable  data type to use  for course code ? and char is the one that i should use for section right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `String` as data type for Course Code. You can write both numbers and letters by using it. And for section, yes, `char` will be suitable for it.

Comment: thank  you very much :D ; exactly what i want to hear

Comment: `char` will be suitable until needing to process `ENG101 EF` (where does the 'F' go?) .. pay attention to the domains and business rules.

Comment: @user2864740 you are right but I assumed they will only use 1 character in their assignment.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @user2864740  but in my project  section only need 1 caracter so i think char is enough . between if it was 2 like u said ( EF) should i use string instead ?

Comment: @AliZgheib Yes, as then it's "just text" (which can still have constraints).

Answer (score 2):

If you're capturing user input, use a String for everything.

Reason? You may request a number, but the user can type anything. Your code needs to handle bad input.

Comment: This is for *reading* the input (eg. before parsing into a suitable type), but not *storing/handling* the transformed input.

Comment: @user286 anything that doesn't need to be converted to another type (like the numbers) should be left as-is. Using a string to atore a single character is fine, because there's no extra code required. By all means assert its length is 1.

Comment: "everything" covers "everything" such as numbers - it is confusing that these are mentioned here when not referring to the grades! - whereas "the course name and section" would just cover .. those. But I agree - I would also use a String for the course and section, as noted in my answer. The teacher _may_ want a char "for efficiency" (and it is important to be able to explain why using a char might [not] be a more suitable choice), but .. I digress .. and I already gave a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `String` for arbitrary text.

If the section code is *always* present<sup>1</sup> and is *never more* than character than a `char` can be used.

However, I would still use a String for consistency, flexibility, and easy of use. The teacher may prefer this based on the "efficient"cy they are going for.

---

<sup>1</sup>The is a soft "always": while `char` cannot represent null a sentinel (eg. `'\0'` or `' '`) can be used to indicate 'no section specified'. Using such a sentinel to supplement null can also (but does not always) lead to more logic work - in particular when the record is displayed.

In any case, it is probably best to *not* switch to `Character` just for the null as this is most likely outside of the scope of current course work.

Comment: Never mind sentinels; if you must use char (I wouldn't) use the wrapper Character, which *can* be null.

Comment: @Bohemian A valid point - the answer is tailored to context, where I assume (correctly or incorrectly) that only the 'basics' have been covered.

Comment: Surely wrappers are basics: since 1.5 autoboxing they are part of the JLS

Comment: @Bohemian Basic in context of the course, based on the question asked. I was providing a reason why a `char` might not be appropriate - dare me for saying too much of ways to solve the issue or clarify my wording!

Comment: The concept of "sentinal" is waaay more advanced than wrappers. IMHO a good percentage of professional programmers would not be familiar with the concept.

Comment: @Bohemian Then those 'professionals' need to go back to school (well, not school, but how can one *not* understand this concept and program in a modern procedural - with OO or without - language?). And what happened to the pre-null generation? (At least in American English it's 'sentinel value', like little soldiers on guard.)